# Paypal Express Checkout to pay referrals

Tags: html, paypal, checkout, referrals

I am building a site that will pay members for referrals.  I am using Wordpress and I am convinced that everything will work well up to the point where I need to pay a current member who refers a new member.  Paypal Express Checkout seems like the best option for parallel payments.  I am willing to pay someone to help.

Comment: EC is for receiving payments. If you are making payments you should look at Mass Pay or Payouts

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my question/problem.....new members will be paying for my content and I want to divide that payment between myself and the existing member who referred the new member.

Comment: I am the developer of [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/).  I can do this for you.  The procedure would be exactly what @PayPal_MSI_Tiffany outlined.  Keep in mind that a parallel payment will show the split to the buyer during checkout.  If you want to hide the split so the buyer only sees a single "seller" then you'll need to do a Chained payment, which would require Adaptive Payments API instead of Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows how to make parallel payments with Express Checkout: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

It says while parallel payments follow the normal Express Checkout flow, they differ in the following ways:

- The SetExpressCheckout request includes different items offered by
  multiple merchants.
- The SetExpressCheckout request contains primary information, as well as optional secondary information that adds detail to the items
  being purchased.
- To capture the payment, your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request must itemize the different merchants and payment amounts.